# state is not getting empty after setting in empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

when I click on the logout that time I want to remove all the states.so what I am doing,

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  LoginReducer,
  UserJobs,
  Technologies,
  QuizData,
  MediumQuizData,
  HighQuizData,
  FetchedQuestions,
  GetAnalitics
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_REQUEST) {
    state = undefined
  }
  return appReducer(state, action)
}

export default rootReducer
```

In my store

```
export default function configureStore() {
    let store = createStore(appReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
    return store;
}
```

onclick of logout

```
handleLogout = () => {
        this.props.logoutUser();
    }


export function logoutUser() {
    return {
        type: LOGOUT_REQUEST
    }
}
```

Reducer -

```
const initialState = {
    Low: [
        {
            id: 'L0',
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            level: 'EASY'
        }
    ],
}
export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case QUIZ_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                Low: action.data,
                error: false,
            }
        case ADD_NEW:
            return {
                ...state,
                Low: action.data,
                error: false,
            }
        case REMOVE_TECH:
            return {
                ...state,
                Low: action.data,
                error: false,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This reducer has some data which gets added when user do something, like I do have three select options , when user selects this gets updated that means that array gets all that value. so when I log out this values remains same in that state.

Here it should set all the reducer values to the initial states, but when I click on the logout button that time it is setting undefined first and then immediately it prints the another state that has all the data which was set for that state. So, I am not understanding why this is happening.

Comment: Have you got any error in console?

Comment: Does it even get to the line where you set it to undefined? And why undefined? Would set it to an empty object.

Comment: No console errors.

Comment: Yes it goes to that line. it prints the undefined first and then again prints the state which has that data

Comment: @ganesh does one of your reducer [mutate the state](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) (instead to replace it)? Can you show the codebase of the reducer which data persists after log out?

Comment: @Alex I have updated my reducer code please check.

Comment: @genesh it looks good

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return  state = undefined,

```
 if (action.type === LOGOUT_REQUEST) {
   return state = undefined
  }
```

otherwise appreducer will always have the current state. When you return an undefined state Store sets it to the initial state.

If you want to keep some items in your reducers, and not clear them out, for example Locales or some common modules for a guest and user, you can do something like this:

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'LOG_OUT') {
    const localeReducer = state.localeReducer;
    return Object.assign({}, initialState, {
      localeReducer,
    });
  }

  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

Comment: just `return undefined`

Comment: I mean directly return state = undefined

Comment: const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_REQUEST) {
    return state = undefined
  }   I tried this  bit its giving now errors when I hit url that time itself.        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LoginReducer' of undefined
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (Header.js:43)

Comment: You need to have LoginReducer in your initial state i think

Comment: @alex can you please elaborate the answer?

Comment: You can copy my suggestion and replace localeReducer with LoginReducer and that should work. Do you have any initial state in your application?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, the state is persisted across the action dispatches.
When I say persisted, it means we replace the current state specific reducer objects based on action type passed in action object respecting immutability. So app reducer is one of the parent reducer that is the starting point to decide where to update the state. So for some action you want to clear all the state in store and set it to initialstate. You need to send a black object instead of passed in the current state.

In here on logout action you can do something like this:

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  let copyState = state
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_REQUEST) {
    copyState = {}
  }
  return appReducer(copyState, action)
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated !!

Comment: It empty the state but the values remains the same

Comment: Which all values remain same?

Comment: every reduvers values remains same

Answer (score 0):

[Redux doc](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) states about `combineReducers`:

> Note that each of these reducers is managing its own part of the global state. The state parameter is different for every reducer, and corresponds to the part of the state it manages. [It's not magic](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/428#issuecomment-129223274).

So redux [store the state internally (privately)](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L61), and [the only way to change data in store is - to dispatch an action](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L8).

I don't think you need to clear out all your state, because as you mentioned in a comment - an error that subscribed component can't read undefined is thrown. What you really need - is to **put your state to the initial values**.

If you prefer it to do the way you've already started it might be import the `initialState` of every reducer, and for `LOGOUT_REQUEST` return an object with the initial tree:

```
import { initialState as LoginReducer } from './LoginReducer';
import { initialState as UserJobs } from './UserJobs';
...

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_REQUEST) {
    return {
      LoginReducer,
      UserJobs,
      ... // all other initial values should be here as well
    }
  }
  return appReducer(state, action)
}
```

Second solution is to listen to `LOGOUT_REQUEST` in every single reducer and return the `initialState`:

```
 const initialState = {
    Low: [
        ...
    ],
}
export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case QUIZ_DATA:
            ...
        case 'LOGOUT_REQUEST':
            return initialState;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi actually, I was aware about the second solution, which one of them will be more efficient ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isJdSelected' of undefined
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (LandingScreen.js:36)  Its giving this error on the logout that means its calling the action but not returning the staate

Comment: const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_REQUEST) {
    console.log("return in this");
    return {
      LoginReducerLog,
      UserJobsLog,
      TechnologiesLog,
      QuizDataLog,
      MediumQuizDataLog,
      HighQuizDataLog,
      FetchedQuestionsLog,
      GetAnaliticsLog
    }
  }
  console.log("final state", state);
  return appReducer(state, action)
}

Comment: @genesh you exported `initialState` for every reducer, and used it as reducer name in imported file, right? So i.e. `LoginReducerLog` is initial state holder, not the actual reducer function, right?

Comment: @genesh, idk, for me both solutions are fine.

Comment: @genesh, which reducer manages `isJdSelected`? Did you export his initial state correctly?